# How to change the new version RAC(ReactiveCocoa) in a project?

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa-4

When I open my iOS project built before the iOS 10 was released, I find it has an error about the ReactiveCocoa because of the version of swift. I try to use the method provided by Github, but it seems I failed. There are at least 18 errors when I try to convert to current swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's RAC Releases for each Swift version, so if you're updating an old(er) codebase to a new version of swift, you will need to update RAC to the appropriate version.

- [RAC 4.x](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/v4.2.2) is for Xcode 7.3.x/Swift 2.2.x or Xcode 8.0.x/Swift 2.3.x
- [RAC 5.x](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/5.0.3) is compatible with Swift 3.0 and 3.1.
- [RAC 6.x](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/6.0.0-rc.3) (not yet released) will be for Swift 3.1 with preliminary support of Swift 3.2 and Swift 4.0.